# Ruby on rails Tutorial Missing partial articles/_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have just started using Ruby on rails and have been following the tutorial @ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

The problem I have got, is with 5.12 Using partials to clean up duplication in views. 
I am getting the error  ActionView::MissingTemplate in Articles#new.
It is looking for _form.html.erb , which is in the directory /app/views/articles/. So not sure why it cannot find it.

**articles controller for new**

```
def new
 @article = Article.new
end
```

**articles view for new**

```
<h1>New article</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

**articles view for _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this article from being saved:
     </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>

< % end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated, need to know how to solve before going on to next part.

Comment: Can you post the exact error in the question?

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Articles#new

Showing /home/gazza/.rbenv/myapp/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

Missing partial articles/_form, application/_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/gazza/.rbenv/myapp/app/views"

Extracted source (around line #4):

2
3
4
5
6
7
              
'code'

<h1>New article</h1>
 
<%= render 'form' %>
 
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %> 'code'

Comment: What is the partial name and its location?

Comment: Not sure what the partial name is as it didn't mention in tutorial, but I would say its form.  The path is /app/views/articles/_form.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have got it to work by renaming `_form.html.erb` to`_form` as the error is looking for `/apps/views/_form`. I don't know if this is the correct way to solve the problem, as its says in the tutorial to name the file `_form.html.erb`.
would this cause issues in future doing it this way?

Comment: it depends on what templating engine you are using. if it is ERB(default) then it should be _form.html.erb(if you want to execute ruby code in html) or _form.html. The new action will look for new view in `app/views/articles/new.html.erb.` you can render form partial in new view.

Comment: @GazSmith I am not sure this is related, but in `_form.html.erb`, last line `< % end %>`, there seems to have an extra space after <

Comment: Hi, in the actual file their is no space, but thanks for pointing it out. Still not sure why this happening when I use the full file name _form.html.erb.

Comment: I am using the default ERB Templating, I know I can render in new view, but what this doing, is using partial for new and edit forms, so it is pointing to _form.html.erb for both of these views instead of using 2 different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file name, maybe you copied it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I changed the file name to '_form.erb' and it worked. Still puzzled why the full suffix of 'html.erb' didn't work.